# Tensorflow Training - Empty Data Set when using repeat()?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using Tensorflow 1.1.4 and trying to train with a validation / test split.

I'm building my data set using `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`

My initial csv set :

```
def get_dataset(file_path,  BATCH_SIZE, NUM_EPOCHS, COLUMN_NAMES, **kwargs,):  
   dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset( file_path,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,na_value="?",num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, column_names=COLUMN_NAMES, ignore_errors=True, shuffle=True,* *kwargs)
   return dataset
```

I then map some functions to my data set to format data how my model needs:

```
  csv_dataset = get_dataset(label_file, BATCH_SIZE, NUM_EPOCHS, COLUMN_NAMES)

  #make a new data set from our csv by mapping every value to the above function
  split_dataset = csv_dataset.map(split_csv_to_path_and_labels)  

  # make a new datas set that loads our images from the first path 
  image_and_labels_ds = split_dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_image_batch, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

  # update our image floating point range to match -1, 1
  ds = image_and_labels_ds.map(change_range)
```

My first attempt at splitting test / train / val like so:

```
  BATCH_SIZE = 64
  NUM_EPOCHS = 10
  DATASET_SIZE = ( lenopenreadlines(label_file) - 1) # remove header

  train_size = int(0.7 * DATASET_SIZE)
  val_size = int(0.15 * DATASET_SIZE)
  test_size = int(0.15 * DATASET_SIZE)

  train_dataset = ds.take(train_size)
  test_dataset = ds.skip(train_size)
  val_dataset = test_dataset.skip(test_size)
  test_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_size)

  steps_per_epoch =  int(train_size // BATCH_SIZE) 
  val_steps_per_epoch = int( (val_size // BATCH_SIZE) ) 

  history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, validation_data=val_dataset, validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch, validation_freq=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

On the last step of my last training epoch I receive this error:

```
70/71 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0760 - acc: 0.8250
WARNING:tensorflow:Your dataset iterator ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your iterator can generate at least `validation_steps * epochs` batches (in this case, 1 batches). You may need touse the repeat() function when building your dataset. WARNING:tensorflow:Your dataset iterator ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your iterator can generate at least `validation_steps * epochs` batches (in this case, 1 batches). You may need touse the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

Looking into this, its clear my sample size for one of my labels is lower than the batch count. However, the error above mentions I can use `ds.repeat()`, and google searching similar issues indicates I could in theory try `tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder()`

However, I cant get either of these to work.

If I add

```
  train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat(1)
  test_dataset = test_dataset.repeat(1)
  val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat(1)
```

I still receive the `Empty Data Set` and same warning from above.

If I use

```
  train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
  test_dataset = test_dataset.repeat()
  val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat()
```

I receive a warning about using an infinitely repeating data set and it bails.

If I add

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(BATCH_SIZE))
test_dataset = test_dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(BATCH_SIZE))
val_dataset = val_dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(BATCH_SIZE))
```

I also receive the empty data set warning.

Also, I can train just fine if I don't use a val / test split (use the same batch size and epoch step math with no validation s and no splits but obviously no one wants that.

```
  steps_per_epoch =  int( DATASET_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE )
  history = model.fit(ds, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)
```

What are other strategies to fix this issue? My sample sizes are typically in the few hudreds to thousands

Comment: Where do you define your iterator? do you use one iterator for all the data sets?

Comment: Ah good Q. Let me add my ds iterator code above using `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` . In short, I make a single iterator and then augment that with some functions to extract images from paths and get my labels. That all works as I can train sans validation. Maybe I have an issue with the iterator? Gimme a moment ill pass that code there.

Comment: Updated to add some context. LMK if the above is helpful or you need more info. Much obliged!

Comment: I think your intuition helped lead me to the issue. I was specifying the number of epochs to the `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` which means it doesnt repeat indefinitely. This caused the other repeat functions to fail, for, I dont know why. I was finally able to get to my validation phase.
God TF is a dense dense unfriendly API...

Comment: Sorry that I was not able to follow up after wards, but it is good your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val_ds = dataset.unbatch().take(val_size).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = dataset.unbatch().skip(val_size).take(train_size).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_ds = dataset.unbatch().skip(train_size + val_size).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

the `.unbatch` should fix the issue

This takes val_size samples, then skips this samples and takes train_size samples and finally the rest of the data ends in test_ds.